# Regular Expression which read whole number and decimal numbers ending with xx.5

Tags: java, regex

how to write a regular expression so that it accepts only whole numbers and decimal ending with .5. I try the following but it reads only 0.5 and whole numbers. I want it to read any number ending with '.5'.

```
^0\.5|\d+$
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
^\d+(\.5)?$
```

The problem with your regex is that it only matches 0 in the start of the string in case the `.5` is also matched.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
^\d+(\.5)?$
```

Comment: @Samantha weired. ASked 18 questions before and didn't accept even a single one..

Comment: I just saw the same thing, @Samantha you need to accept and upvote/downvote answers when they are given. when you don't do it people won't be encouraged to answer your questions, please read the Tour section of stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry guys I was not aware about this upvote. Thanks